# some kind of queue for asynctask

Tags: android, queue, android-asynctask

Hello
I have ListView with list of files. i click item and start to download this file in asynctask.
then i click another one and it must be put in queue, wait for that file and start ot download after it finishes. i can make some class that will hold all clicked links, and pass it to asynctask downloading part? and than somehow process them. but want to know is it the right way?
any links of sugestions? thanks

Comment: Queues are fine if you don't care when they get done, as long as they do get done.  If some need to get done earlier than others, use a priority queue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're set on using AsyncTask then, yeah, hold your clicked links and kick off new tasks when appropriate. You should note that AsyncTask is like the 'pocket knife' for threading in Android apps.

If you really need to manage a bunch of background tasks, and it sounds like you do, take a look at ThreadPoolExecutor. You get a lot of flexibility.
[BlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)
[ThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)
[More Info](http://foo.jasonhudgins.com/2010/05/limitations-of-asynctask.html)
[Example](http://bobah.net/d4d/source-code/misc/thread-pool-executor-example-j2ee)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at HandlerThread and the Handler class.  You need one handler to pass tasks to the background HandlerThread and another for the UI thread to pass results back to the UI

Answer (score 2):

Even though old, got here from Google: consider an IntentService.